# Return nested EF objects in a asmx webservice in c#

Tags: c#, web-services, entity-framework, asmx

i'm creating a webservice in C# using Entity Framework to retrive the data.

I have 2 related tables (Person, Role).

Each Person has a Role associated.

I would like that the returned objet is a Person and that the associated Role is included.

If I execute a query like this:

```
From p in ef.Person.Include("Role") select p
```

in debug I can see that the Role object for each Person is loaded.

But the returned/generated XML contains only a RoleReference wich gives me information about the related object, but not the object itself.

I tried to add the Serializable attribute to the classes generated by the entity framwork and also the xmlInclude attribute to the webmethod but nothing changes.

How can i solve this problem?

thanks!

Flavio

Comment: Can you show the code, used to return the query result?

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing the IEnumerable? Try a .ToList() to stop the lazy loading and pass that instead.

Comment: The Lazy Loading is disabled. I have tried to use toList but it didn't work.
If I stop the code in debug mode to check the query result, it is correct, but the returned XML generated by the webservice contains only the regerence to the nested object.

Comment: Can you provide more code? Maybe the web service class declaration and the serialization code?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own classes Person & Role and create for them mappers:

```
public class MyPerson
{
   [DataMember]
   public int ID {get; set;}
   [DataMember]
   public string Name {get; set;}
   ...
   [DataMember]
   public MyRole PersonRole {get; set;}
}

public class MyRole
{
   [DataMember]
   public int ID {get; set;}
   ...
}
```

Mapper:

```
MyRole Mapper(EFRole role)
{
   return new MyRole() {
       id = role.id, ...
   }
}

MyPerson Mapper(EFPerson person)
{
     return new MyPerson() {
         id = person.id, 
         ....
         PersonRole = (person.Role != null ? Mapper(person.Role) : null;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's to "complicated" for the purpose of the application (it's just a test to compare WCF Data Service based on EF with "asmx" webservice based on the same EF)...i will try it later...

Answer (score 0):

Use a Partial class called Person that includes the Role nested object, or Role needed properties.

Comment: Could you please describe a more detailed answer, maybe with some example code.